# django import a variable from server specific settings file

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have the following settings structure. The placement of the settings folder is as per autogenerated config. Instead of having a settings.py, I have created a settings folder, and the contents are as below.

local.py is for local machine, and production.py is for production server.

Both local.py and production.py inherit from _base.py 
.

```
├── _base.py
├── __init__.py
├── local.py
├── production.py
└── secrets.py
```

Earlier, there was only one settings file, so I could happily in my views write -

The `SOME_VARIABLE` is different for production and local.

`from settings import SOME_VARIABLE` and it worked well.

This is how I `validate` now - `python manage.py validate --settings=settings.local` it throws an import error.

**ImportError: cannot import name SOME_VARIABLE**

Any ways I could go about importing things in my views file, and avoid the import error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different patterns for handling settings across different installations.  Perhaps simplest for your needs is [The One True Way](https://speakerdeck.com/jacobian/the-best-and-worst-of-django?slide=81).

If you want to do something a bit more complicated but (in my opinion) better:

- http://bruno.im/2013/may/18/django-stop-writing-settings-files/
- Or http://django-configurations.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- Or if you're feeling experimental, https://github.com/seddonym/bobsleigh (Disclaimer: this is my project and in very early stages).